# Exponent of product not differentiable?

Tags: real-analysis, multivariable-calculus, derivatives

[image]

Using the above definition, I'm trying to prove that the function $f(x, y) = e^{xy}$ is differentiable. (Here "$= o(h)$" means that is goes to $0$ faster than $h$ (in norm).) The problem is that we end up with 
$$f(p+h) = f(p)· f(h) · e^{p_1h_2 + p_2h_1}
$$
Even if we were to realise that (as we need only consider small $h$), $f(h) \approx 1+ h_1h_2$ and $e^{p_1h_2 + p_2h_1} \approx 1 + p_1h_2 + p_2h_1$, we still have no *linear* map $D$ doing the job, as we must still multiply the whole bunch by the factor $f(p)$. Does this mean that under this definition, $e^{xy}$ is *not* differentiable?

Comment: You do have a linear map that does the job. It is the $0$ function, which I'll denote by $Z$ :$$f(h_1,h_2) = 1 +  h_1h_2 + \dots = 1+Z(h) + o(h).$$

Comment: Thanks! I will go back to sleep now..

Comment: On second thought, I'm not convinced yet. You write $+ o(h)$, but in checking that I find that it isn't. Namely, the limit $\lim_\limits{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2} \to 0} \frac{p_1h_2 + p_2h_1}{\sqrt{h_1^2 + h_2^2}}$ doesn't seem to be defined.

Comment: I thought you were sleeping. See my answer.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In my comment I was considering the case $p=(0,0)$ as I thought you were with $f(h) \approx 1+ h_1h_2.$ Let's do it for general $p.$

$$e^{(p_1+ h_1)(p_2+h_2)} = e^{p_1p_2+ h_1p_2+h_2p_1 +h_1h_2}$$ $$= e^{p_1p_2} e^{h_1p_2+h_2p_1 +h_1h_2} = e^{p_1p_2} (1 + (h_1p_2+h_2p_1 +h_1h_2) + O(h^2))$$ $$ = e^{p_1p_2}  + e^{p_1p_2}(h_1p_2+h_2p_1)+O(h^2).$$

Since $p$ is fixed, the last line has the form

$$e^{p_1p_2} +T(h_1,h_2) + O(h^2),$$

where $T$ is the linear map $(h_1,h_2)\to e^{p_1p_2}(h_1p_2+h_2p_1).$